# Symfony: Functional Test with PRE_SUBMIT Form Event

Tags: symfony, addeventlistener, form-submit, functional-testing

i'm trying to test a form with a PRE_SUBMIT Form my FormType Class looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('productType', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Software' => 'software',
                    'Television' => 'television',
                    'Giftcard' => 'giftcard',
                    'Bitte wählen' => '',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('productNumber', TextType::class)
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event)
            {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();

                if ($data['productType'] === 'giftcard') {
                    $form->add('value', TextType::class);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

i have no clue how to do it, i only can reach the field value if i submit the form like this.

```
$client->submitForm('Submit', [
            'product[productType]' => 'giftcard',
            'product[productNumber]' => 'C123123',
            'product[title]' => 'TestCard',
        ]);
```

i cant do a second submit like this. But the form looks fine after the first submit.
Hopefully someone can help me or give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it like this with a pre submitted form. Now its working fine.
If you want to add a new value with this event you shut take the crawler again after the first submit and add the value to the form.

```
    public function testRedirectAfterCreateGiftcard(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient([
            'debug' => false,
        ]);
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://localhost/product/create');
        $client->followRedirects();

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form();
        $values = $form->getPhpValues();
        $values['product']['productType'] = 'giftcard';
        $values['product']['productNumber'] = 'B122222';
        $values['product']['title'] = 'Test';
        $client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $values, $form->getPhpFiles());
        $form->setValues($values);
        $client->submitForm('Submit');

        $form2 = $client->getCrawler()->selectButton('Submit')->form();
        $values2 = $form2->getPhpValues();
        $values2['product']['value'] = '25';
        $form2->setValues($values2);
        $client->submit($form2);

        $this->assertRouteSame('app_product_view', ['productType' => 'giftcard']);
    }
```